# Slice notation in Scala?

Tags: python, scala, slice

Is there something similar to [the slice notation in Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) in Scala?

I think this is really a useful operation that should be incorporated in all languages.

Comment: Well, some people prefer a language which stays small, simple and clean. Not every little syntactic sugar is worth the trouble.

Comment: I'm not convinced that Scala is small and simple though. Compared to something like lua, anyway...

Comment: Comparing to Python Scala doesn't look so small and simple, it has many more constructs than Python.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
scala> import collection.IterableLike
import collection.IterableLike

scala> implicit def pythonicSlice[A, Repr](coll: IterableLike[A, Repr]) = new {
     |   def apply(subrange: (Int, Int)): Repr = coll.slice(subrange._1, subrange._2)
     | }
pythonicSlice: [A,Repr](coll: scala.collection.IterableLike[A,Repr])java.lang.Object{def apply(subrange: (Int, Int)): Repr}

scala> val list = List(3, 4, 11, 78, 3, 9)
list: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 11, 78, 3, 9)

scala> list(2 -> 5)
res4: List[Int] = List(11, 78, 3)
```

Will this do?

Disclaimer: Not properly generalized.

---

**EDIT:**

```
scala> case class PRange(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int = 1)
defined class PRange

scala> implicit def intWithTildyArrow(i: Int) = new {
     |   def ~>(j: Int) = PRange(i, j)
     | }
intWithTildyArrow: (i: Int)java.lang.Object{def ~>(j: Int): PRange}

scala> implicit def prangeWithTildyArrow(p: PRange) = new {
     |   def ~>(step: Int) = p.copy(step = step)
     | }
prangeWithTildyArrow: (p: PRange)java.lang.Object{def ~>(step: Int): PRange}

scala> implicit def pSlice[A](coll: List[A]) = new {
     |   def apply(prange: PRange) = {
     |     import prange._
     |     coll.slice(start, end).grouped(step).toList.map(_.head)
     |   }
     | }
pSlice: [A](coll: List[A])java.lang.Object{def apply(prange: PRange): List[A]}

scala> val xs = List.range(1, 10)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> xs(3 ~> 9)
res32: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

scala> xs(3 ~> 9 ~> 2)
res33: List[Int] = List(4, 6, 8)
```

Comment: gr8.can you modify it to take negative and steps also?

Comment: which scala are you using ? I'm using 2.7.It say's 'IterableLike' is not a member of collection.

Comment: @Emil: Negative - not possible, `apply(Int)` is already defined. Steps - What are they?

Comment: @Emil: I am using Scala 2.8.0 final.

Comment: Use Scala 2.8, 2.7 is outdated.

Comment: @Factor:Check this so [ans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation/509295#509295) for steps.

Comment: u can look here for describe of implicits: http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch08.html#Implicits

Comment: @Emil: Check the edit. Added steps. I wasn't able to generalize it, so used the `List` type.

Comment: See my addition of a general solution which works with Strings/Lists/Arrays etc below

Answer (score 55):

Equivalent method in Scala (with a slightly different syntax) exists for all kinds of sequences:

```
scala> "Hello world" slice(0,4)
res0: String = Hell

scala> (1 to 10) slice(3,5)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(4, 5)
```

The biggest difference compared to slicing in Python is that start and end indices are mandatory in Scala.

Comment: is overloading of operator's possible to use it like python syntax.I think that's more elegant.

Comment: @Emil Maybe you could use implicit classes to give it an easier syntax

Answer (score 9):

See the [ScalaAPI here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html)

So not the same notational convenience, but the operation is there

> def   slice  (from: Int, until: Int) 
>   : Seq[A]
>
> Selects an interval of elements.
>
> Selects an interval of elements.
>
> Note: c.slice(from, to) is equivalent
>   to (but possibly more efficient than)
>   c.drop(from).take(to - from)
>
> from the index of the first returned element in this sequence. until 
>   the index one past the last returned element in this sequence.
>
> returns
>
> a sequence containing the elements starting at index from and extending
>   up to (but not including) index until
>   of this sequence.
>
> definition classes: IterableLike →
>   TraversableLike

Answer (score 2):

Note that this does not quite work by using `apply`, but it **generalizes** to lists, strings, arrays, etc:

```
implicit def it2sl[Repr <% scala.collection.IterableLike[_, Repr]](cc: Repr) = new {
  def ~>(i : Int, j : Int) : Repr = cc.slice(i,j)
}
```

The usage is:

```
scala> "Hello World" ~> (3, 5)
res1: java.lang.String = lo

scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4) ~> (0, 2)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') ~> (1, 3)
res3: Array[Char] = Array(b, c)
```

You might want to rename the method to something else that takes your fancy. **Except** `apply` (because there is already a conversion from `String` to `StringLike` which decorates String with an `apply` method - similarly with `ArrayOps` - and there is already an apply method on other collection types such as `List`).

Thanks for *Daniel* for the hint to use a view bound.